# Google Vision API hitting request limit even though I am sending way less no of requests

Tags: google-api, vision, google-cloud-vision

The Google Vision API has a limit of 10 requests per second. I have put a time gap of 10 seconds between each request and even then the response I get for every request after the second or third request is as below. The first request always works just fine.

> , https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?alt=json
>   returned "Insufficient tokens for quota group and limit
>   DefaultGroupUSER-100s using the limit by ID ******@*******.

What could be the reason that this is happening. Is there something the documentation that I am missing ?. The images I try to pass are in the range of 100-150 KB size only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do service authentication
take a look at:
http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/

> Note that the default credentials obtained by running gcloud auth
>   application-default login from the Google Cloud SDK are not suitable
>   for use with this API. (They will work initially, but implicitly have
>   a very small request quota.)